# How to add a $\beta$ and capacity term to a variational autoencoder?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, keras, autoencoders, kullback-leibler

Vanilla [variational autoencoders](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6114) add a Kullback–Leibler divergence (KL) term to the loss function, i.e. the loss is a combination of the reconstruction error (e.g. cross entropy or MSE) and the KL divergence, the latter of which assumes the following form:

$$
-D_{KL} = \frac{1}{2} \sum (1 + log(\sigma^2) - \mu^2 - \sigma^2)
$$

In practise, this [typically assumes](https://keras.io/examples/variational_autoencoder/) the following form in a `keras` custom loss function:

```py
# y_true and y_pred are 2d arrays of batch_samples x n_features
def vae_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  # keras MSE returns per sample mean of MSE across features
  reconstruction_loss = losses.mse(y_true, y_pred)
  # weight reconstruction loss by dimensionality
  reconstruction_loss *= raw_dim
  # per sample and per latent dimension kl loss
  kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mu) - K.exp(z_log_var)
  # sum across the latent dimensions for a per-sample kl loss
  kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
  # add the per sample reconstruction and kl_loss and return the batch mean
  return K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
```

[$\beta$-VAE](https://openreview.net/forum?id=Sy2fzU9gl) variants encourage better disentangling through use of the $\beta$ parameter, which can be used to increase the emphasis on the Kullback–Leibler divergence (KL) in the loss function, i.e. increased disentangling of the latent dimensions but generally worse reconstruction, i.e. the KL part of the loss function becomes:

$$
-\beta(\frac{1}{2} \sum (1 + log(\sigma^2) - \mu^2 - \sigma^2))
$$

In the paper [Understanding disentangling in $\beta$-VAE](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03599) the authors propose adding an annealed capacity term $C$ that increases the informational capacity of the autoencoder. This term is increased from $0$ to full strength of $C$ over successive epochs of training.

$$
-\beta(|\frac{1}{2} \sum (1 + log(\sigma^2) - \mu^2 - \sigma^2) - C|)
$$

As far as I understand this is a relatively straight-forward matter of adding the $\beta$ and capacity terms to the loss function. I've found two differing implementations:

A) [One approach](https://github.com/YannDubs/disentangling-vae/blob/535bbd2e9aeb5a200663a4f82f1d34e084c4ba8d/disvae/models/losses.py#L450) first takes the mean across all samples per latent dimension:

```py
  # per sample and per latent dimension kl loss
  kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mu) - K.exp(z_log_var)
  # take kl loss mean across all samples per latent dimension
  kl_loss = -0.5 * K.mean(kl_loss, axis=0)
  # then take the sum across latent dimensions
  kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss)
  # apply beta and capacity
  kl_loss = beta * K.abs(kl_loss - capacity)
```

B) [Another approach](https://github.com/google-research/disentanglement_lib/blob/a64b8b9994a28fafd47ccd866b0318fa30a3c76c/disentanglement_lib/methods/unsupervised/vae.py#L117) first sums across the latent dimensions, then takes the mean across batch samples:

```py
  # per sample and per latent dimension kl loss
  kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mu) - K.exp(z_log_var)
  # take kl loss sum across latent dimensions
  kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(kl_loss, axis=1)
  # then take the mean across latent dimensions
  kl_loss = K.mean(kl_loss)
  # apply beta and capacity
  kl_loss = beta * K.abs(kl_loss - capacity)
```

(Not shown is a callback function which increases the capacity term from 0 to full strength over the duration of the training epochs.)

I wish to confirm:

- Are the above interpretations of the annealed capacity $\beta$-VAE loss function correct?
- The authors of the [$\beta$-VAE](https://openreview.net/forum?id=Sy2fzU9gl) paper discuss normalising $\beta$ where $\beta_{norm} = \frac{\beta M}{N}$ is multiplied by the number of latent dimensions and dividing through the number of (batch) samples. What do people typically do in practise?
- Similarly, should reconstruction loss be scaled by the number of latent dimensions, or is it better to only scale the $\beta$ parameter?
- At the step casting the combined $(D_{KL} - C)$ term to an absolute number: my interpretation is that this step prevents this part of the loss function from approaching too close to zero (per strength of $C$). i.e. if the capacity of $C$ is greater than the $D_{KL}$ loss it would actually lead to an increase in the $D_{KL}$ loss, as if it encourages at least a certain amount of $D_{KL}$ loss in order to increase the information carrying capacity? Is this intuition correct and are there situations where casting negative values to positive could cause the loss function to behave oddly?

Thanks.

Comment: but to what value exacly should you set the C and why? I cant find a clear explanation or any concrete values anywhere ?!

Comment: @SheppLogan I never did find a clear answer on tuning C. In the end I tried a range of parameters to find a value of C that allows all available dimensions to be used (too low C prevents model from using all dims) while not increasing too much beyond that to encourage disentangling. See section 6.2 in this preprint: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.15363.pdf